# How do I display an element based on a dynamically generated elements text?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

**EDIT:** I'm such an idiot... Marvin and CK MacLeod, your comments helped me find the problem.
While the code was loading (I inspected the page), I think there was a conflict with another JS block I added. This was all added via the customizer which. So I've installed a plugin which allows me to add the script directly to the templates I needed the code to run on, and it works.
Thanks so much for everyone's help and super sorry to have wasted anyone's time.

---

I'm trying to display an element based on the inner text of another element whose text is dynamically generated in WordPress.
I'm still new to JavaScript, so have no idea where I'm going wrong and would greatly appreciate any help :)
The code below is what I've used and while it works in the w3schools editor, it doesn't work in WordPress.

The idea behind this is to show a specific shipping policy based on the store name.

```
function displayPolicy() {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("wcfm_dashboard_item_title")[0];
  var x = c.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var y = document.getElementById("shippingPolicy");
  if (x === "Baby Fantasy") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
  };
};

displayPolicy();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! By doesn't work, do you mean it causes an error, or just doesn't do what you want it to do? In the latter case, try `console.log()` x and see what you get.

Comment: document.getElementById("shippingPolicy") this.also returns the array , try y = document.getElementById("shippingPolicy")[0]

Comment: Can you add the HTML that the script is supposed to work on? Also, how are you loading the script? Are you sure that it's being loaded at all?

Comment: your code work ok. https://jsfiddle.net/cbpz7v34/ We need to know the html that you have in order to assist you.